# Using different array's with switch statements

Tags: javascript

I am creating a recycling app and am attempting to use a switch statement to provide the user with instructions on what to do with the item upon entering into an input field. I'm a little turned around on how to call it (I am very new to switch). Eventually I want to have a few different arrays according to material. How would I place the item's within an array in the a switch? Would I be better off with if else statements? Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
const plasticItem = ["Milk Jug , Shampoo, Deodarant, Soda Bottle"];

function recycleItem(plasticItem) {
    let instructions = "";

    switch (true) {
        case plasticItem: 
        instructions = "Put in recycling"; 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `platsticItem` parameter to the function the same as the global variable with the same name?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do with that `switch/case`. Usually you write `switch(variable) { case "some constant": ... }`

Comment: First you'll want to use a proper array: `const plasticItems = ["Milk Jug", "Shampoo", "Deodarant", "Soda Bottle"];`. Next you want to find out if some user input `x` is part of the array. That's what [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is for. The `switch` keyword is a red herring here, you don't need it at all.

Comment: Some people like to use `switch(true)` in a pattern where all the `case` are condition expressions, e.g. `switch (true) { case a < 10: ... break; case a < 20: ... }`. I consider this an abomination.... It's no better than `if (a < 10) ... else if (a < 20) ...`

Comment: Oh man it is. Could I use a few different global variables containing array's  and use them in the switch?

Comment: The primary use of switch is to compare some value X to a bunch of other discrete values A, B, C, etc.

Comment: You could use an object whose keys are the item names and values are the corresponding messages. `{"milk jug": "Put in recycling", "vegetables": "Send to compost", ...}`

Comment: Here's what I would do: https://jsfiddle.net/q403vs1n/

Answer (score 0):

I made this code which should work:

```
function recycleItem(){
        const x = document.querySelector("input").value;
        switch(x) {
          case "Milk Jug":
            console.log("Milk");
            break;
          case "Shampoo":
            // code block
            console.log("Shampoo");
            break;
          case "Deodarant":
            console.log("Deodarant");
            break
          case "Soda Bottle":
            console.log("Soda Bottle");
            break
          default:
            // code block
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Wow guys! Thanks for the support. I now have a way better idea of switch statements and see that going the object route is going to be the best way to get this done. Much appreciated!